# Como faço para printar apenas um mês de uma lista em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Criei um formulário para emitir declarações de endereço para o pessoal do meu bairro (uso pessoal apenas).

Tem uma parte na qual eu preciso imprimir a data nesse estilo: 12 de Maio de 2022.

Queria fazer isso digitando o número do índice durante a execução do código no terminal, mas não sei fazer isso, então acabo tendo que editar o número dentro do código a cada mês que vira:

```
data = input("Hoje é dia: ")

mes = ["0","Janeiro","Fevereiro","Março","Abril","Maio","junho","Julho","Agosto","Setembro","Outubro","Novembro","Dezembro"]

ano = 2022

print("Cidade, " + str(data) + " de " + str(mes[5]) + " de " + str(ano)+".")
```

Comment: Se entendi direito, é só pedir pra digitar o mês e converter para número, e depois pegar o respectivo valor na lista de meses: `m = int(input('digite o mês: '))` e depois pega o `mes[m]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oii!!

Você pode colocar assim:

```
data = input("Hoje é dia: ")
mes_num = input("Informe o numero mês: ")
mes_num = pd.to_numeric(mes_num, errors='ignore')

mes = ["0","Janeiro","Fevereiro","Março","Abril","Maio","junho","Julho","Agosto","Setembro","Outubro","Novembro","Dezembro"]

ano = 2022

print("Cidade, " + str(data) + " de " + str(mes[mes_num]) + " de " + str(ano)+".")
```

Coloquei mais uma caixa de input pra informar o numero do mês e como o input retorna um valor em string, fiz a conversão da string pra int e depois coloquei a variavel que criei no indice que você setava manual.

Comment: Oi, funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda.